# Python script not looping correctly

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I am using this python code to look through a csv, which has dates in one column and values in the other. I am recording the minimum value from each year. My code is not looping through correctly. What's my stupid mistake? Cheers

```
import csv
refMin = 40

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for i in range(1968,2014):
            for row in reader:
                if str(row[0])[:4] == str(i):
                    if float(row[1]) <= refMin:
                        refMin = float(row[1])
            print 'The minimum value for ' + str(i) + ' is: ' + str(refMin)
```

Comment: What's the indication that it's not looping correctly?

Comment: The for-loop associated with 'for row in reader' only iterates for 1968, no other years.

Comment: yes, because once the reader reaches the end, it does not go back to the beginning of the file

Answer (score 4):

The reader can only be iterated once. The first time around the `for i in range(1968,2014)` loop, you consume every item in the reader. So the second time around that loop, there are no items left.

If you want to compare every value of `i` against every row in the file, you could swap your loops around, so that the loop `for row in reader` is on the outside and only runs once, with multiple runs of the `i` loop instead. Or you could create a new reader each time round, although that might be slower.

If you want to process the entire file in one pass, you'll need to create a dictionary of values to replace refMin. When processing each row, either iterate through the dictionary keys, or look it up based on the current row. On the other hand, if you're happy to read the file multiple times, just move the line `reader = csv.reader(...)` inside the outer loop.

Here's an untested idea for doing it in one pass:

```
import csv
import collections
refMin = collections.defaultdict(lambda:40)

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    allowed_years = set(str(i) for i in range(1968,2014))
    for row in reader:
        year = int(str(row[0])[:4])
        if float(row[1]) <= refMin[year]:
            refMin[year] = float(row[1])

for year in range(1968, 2014):
    print 'The minimum value for ' + str(year) + ' is: ' + str(refMin[year])
```

`defaultdict` is just like a regular dictionary except that it has a default value for keys that haven't previously been set.

Comment: That make sense, thank you. Do you know what steps I can take to get around this?

Comment: You could throw in an if statement to test that the year is in that range.

Comment: Instead of trying to check whether `str(row[0])[:4] == str(i)` for every possible year value, try converting the year value from the CSV to `int`, and doing a numeric comparison (like `1968 <= year <= 2014`).

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor that to read the file only once:

```
import csv
refByYear = DefaultDict(list)

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        refByYear[str(row[0])[:4]].append(float(row[1]))
for year in range(1968, 2014):
    print 'The minimum value for ' + str(year) + ' is: ' + str(min(refByYear[str(year)]))
```

Here I store all values for each year, which may be useful for other purposes, or totally useless.